# Couchbase and NoSQL DBs for a serious Web-Application?

Tags: performance, couchbase, business-logic, nosql

I read some posts here, but a real answer I didnt find.
Normally I work and worked with normal SQL Databaeses (MS SQL, MySQL), when I developed applications (ERP, CRM, PPS, Web Shops etc.). A real contact/experience with document-oriented databases in real business was not possible.
Only in a private sector (hobby, experimental projects) I tested MongoDB and CouchDB. The experience was good, but not enough to say "Yes, let it use for business!", because I could not test it in a real environment.
But now, there is a chance to program from zero, which could be a big start for a business.

So my question: 
Can I use Couchebase for a big business application, where thousands users would use it. Is it so fast and with good performance to handling thousnds of queries, requests/reposts etc.?
How looks like with backup and restore?
Where is the limit of couchbase?

Thank you for the anwser.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes.

Your questions are too broad to fully address here.  Couchbase has many real-world installations with clients doing production work at large scale.  You can see several references with write ups of their uses on the Couchbase site.  (Note this is not a complete list of customers, only ones that have agreed to have their use highlighted.)  You will definitely recognize some names.